# FireDac MemTable Filtering Error on XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, firedac

I am get an error that "Expression unexpectedly terminated" when i want to doing on the FireDac MemTable.
I am use that codes

```
with FMemtable1 Do
 begin 
  Filtered :=False;
  Filter   := 'Field1 like ' + ''''+'%'+Edit1.Text+'%'+'''';
  Filtered :=true; 
 end
```

But im not get this error when i was try on the XE6

Comment: try to replace the filter statement bij the following:  'Filter := 'Field1 like ' + QuotedStr(Edit1.Text);

Comment: Thank but i tried i take same result

Comment: Then I think we need some more information.  How is your FDMemtable configured?  Is there a 'Field1' defined by name in the dataset?

Comment: @copilrot you are right .Field1 is a st Ftstrings field.I create just one field I actived FDMemtable after de created that field

Comment: Add `ShowMessage(Filter);` and see what you get. Then switch to using QuotedStr() instead of playing around with all the quad quotes.

Answer (score -1):

this Code not ABC filtering

```
Filter   := 'Field1 like ' + ''''+'%'+Edit1.Text+'%'+''''; // filter Any Letter

Filter := 'Field1 like ' + QuotedStr(Edit1.Text‌​);// filter Exactly Word
```

Comment: Are you able to expand you answer somewhat to explain how your example applies to the question?